# htaccess mods rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Newby to htaccess mods , thankyou for any help

I'm tryin to rewrite the following into a more efficient solution

```
RewriteRule about    http://www.website.co.uk/index.php?/page/about [NC,L]  
RewriteRule testimonials http://www.website.co.uk/index.php?/page/testimonials [NC,L]
```

I want the user to enter

```
www.website.co.uk/page/about etc
```

Can anybody advise, have spent a couple of hours on this & getting nowhere fast!!

Thansks

Comment: The issue is that it's not very efficient, I'd like to achieve this in one command rewrite rule rather than multiple rules

Answer (score 0):

If those are the only two pages you need to redirect use

```
RewriteRule (about|testimonials) /index.php?/page/$1 [NC,L]
```

If you want to serve all your pages like that use

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ /index.php?/page/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks , I will give this a try over the weekend

Comment: I've tried the following :- but the url displayed in the browser is still the ugly one, RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule (about_michelle|contact_michelle|testimonials|packages) http://www.michelledaniels.co.uk/photos/index.php?/page/$1 [NC,L]

Comment: `/photos` where did that come from? It's no where mentioned in your question. Please update it with your directory structure, the location of your htaccess and sample URLs. How you want them to appear and which php file path would actually process the request?

Comment: Stupidly I didn't think it would make a difference. htaccess is in the root & has a redirect :- RedirectMatch permanent ^/$ http://www.michelledaniels.co.uk/photos/   - All i want is to remove the index.php? from appearing in the url, and for the clean url to display in the browser.  So for the following url , remove index.php? http://www.michelledaniels.co.uk/photos/index.php?/categories, thanks for your help

Comment: Finally got this to work using the following - RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^.*page/(.*)$ /photos/index.php?/page/$1 [NC,L]